# std::locale(const char*) freezes ... sometimes. Visual Studio bug?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, locale

Consider the following code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    //auto loc = std::locale("de-DE");  // A
    auto loc = std::locale("");         // B

    ss.imbue(loc);
    ss << 1.01;

    std::cout << "standard formatting:  " << 1.01 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "localized formatting: " << ss.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Now, this works as expected or it freezes in line B. When using line A it is the same but I think that changing from A to B or vice versa leads to a higher chance that it works. It even happened that it worked one time and starting it again it freezes in line A or B respectively.

It is important that all this happens only when I start debugging from within VS 2015. When I execute this program from console it never freezes (release or debug doesn't matter).

So is this a Visual Studio bug?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, and just for your information, but you don't have to cast floating-point literals like `1.01` to `double`, all floating-point literals are, unless suffixed, of type `double` by default. Just like unsuffixed integer literals are of type `int`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks, edited question.

Comment: Could be [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/750951/std-locale-implementation-in-crt-assumes-all-facets-to-be-allocated-on-crt-heap-and-crashes-in-destructor-in-debug-mode-if-a-facet-was-allocated-by-a-custom-allocator)

Comment: @sergej Yeah, maybe. Strange: In the comments one claims to have fixed the bug in 2013 while status is "active". And is there a workaroud? Well, [boost](http://www.boost.org/), I guess.